# How can I handle the user swiping back with Jetpack Compose / Wear OS?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, wear-os

I'm writing a Wear OS application, and have a few places in my app, where if the user goes back, I want to redirect the user to a different screen first, then let them go back as desired.

I was using [BackHandler](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/activity/compose/package-summary#BackHandler(kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function0)), but noticed in testing that it seemed to only work with a back button in the emulator, but swiping back like I do on my physical test device (which has no back button) is not caught by BackHandler.

Is there a way in Wear OS / Jetpack Compose to handle a swipe back in addition to the back button or a way to override swiping from the left edge of the screen to do a different action than take the user back?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have tried the exact same thing and it also didn't work (using latest wear os compose version 1.3.0-alpha01)

Answer (score 0):

This is the Composable I've ended up with after lots of trial and error:

````
/**
 * This detects a user's swipe to dismiss gesture.
 */
@Composable
fun OnDismissed(
    /** Obtain via `navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()` */
    backStack: State<NavBackStackEntry?>,

    /**
     * Obtain like this
     * ```
     * val swipeBoxState = rememberSwipeToDismissBoxState()
     * val navState = rememberSwipeDismissableNavHostState(swipeBoxState)
     * SwipeDismissableNavHost(
     *   ...
     *   state = swipeBoxState
     * )
     */
    swipeBoxState: SwipeToDismissBoxState? = null,

    /**
     * Called when the screen is dismissed.
     */
    onDismissed: () -> Unit
) {
    var targetValue by remember { mutableStateOf<SwipeToDismissValue?>(null) }
    
    val backStackValue = backStack.value
    if (backStackValue != null) {
        val id = rememberSaveable { backStackValue.id }

        // Here, we compare the id upon creation of this composable with the current id of the backstack.
        // We only want to call onDismissed() on the current screen and not any previous screens.
        val isCurrentRoute = id == backStackValue.id

        if (isCurrentRoute && swipeBoxState != null) {
            // This keeps the targetValue always in sync with the boxState.targetValue
            LaunchedEffect(swipeBoxState.targetValue) {
                targetValue = swipeBoxState.targetValue
            }

            DisposableEffect(Unit) {
                onDispose {
                    // If this composable ends up being dismissed while the targetValue is "dismissed",
                    // we can assume that the user has swiped to dismiss the screen (instead of navigating forward, which also dismisses the screen).
                    // Technically, the forward navigation could happen automatically via some logic,
                    // but this is good enough for now until this is fixed:
                    // https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/292590712
                    if (targetValue == SwipeToDismissValue.Dismissed) {
                        onDismissed()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
````

Use like this:

```
val navController = rememberSwipeDismissableNavController()
val swipeBoxState = rememberSwipeToDismissBoxState()
val navState = rememberSwipeDismissableNavHostState(swipeBoxState)

SwipeDismissableNavHost(
    navController = navController,
    startDestination = "screen1",
    state = navState
) {
    composable("screen1") {
        OnDismissed(
            backStack = navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState(),
            swipeBoxState = swipeBoxState
        ) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding `userSwipeEnabled` paramater inside    `SwipeDismissableNavHost` and then setting it true or false using state depending on composable that it requires it. Be sure to update material to latest one, I am using 1.3.0